# Image compression in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a lot of images(about 1,000) in 30kb aproximately, the load size of the index was 45.5mb, if you ask why.

i get the images from a server, then convert to byte array and then to base64 string to send to index in

```
data:image/webp;base64,{0}
```

i use this:

```cs
Html.Raw(String.Format("data:image/webp;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes("\\\\ImageServer\\ImagePathFolder\\Image.JPG".Replace("\\", "\\\\")))))
```

so far the index takes to load about 24 seconds.

I ask for help to compress the images and get at least the half size now i get.

> NOTE: all this code in in ASP.NET MVC with C#

Comment: Is performance the issue? Because if so, compression/decompression will only make things slower.

Comment: You can’t compress your images - they’re already JPEGs. Using Base64 encoding will use 33% more space (it only makes sense to inline images using `data:` URIs if they’re under a few kilobytes where the inefficient encoding makes up for not having to make a separate HTTP request).

Comment: performace was not the issue, the issue was the size, i set all the images in one dataset to load in datatable.

Answer (score 1):

You should return binary-large-objects ("BLOBs", generally anything larger than a kilobyte or so) in a separate request - this has numerous advantages, but the main reasons are

- Browsers can cache individual responses and images.
- They can be transferred directly without encoding them using an inefficient format like Base64 (which effectively uses 1 byte to transfer 6 bits of data).

Whereas using `data:` URIs to include images inline in the page is wasteful because the image data needs to be loaded and encoded to Base64 on every request. Avoid disk IO when you can (additionally your code isn't using Async IO, so it's particularly inefficient).

In ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core, define a new Action to handle requests for images:

```
[HttpGet("images/{imageName}")]
public ActionResult GetImage( String imageName )
{
    String imagefileName = GetImageFileName( imageName ); // don't forget to sanitize input to prevent directory traversal attacks

    // Use `FileResult` to have ASP.NET MVC efficiently load and transmit the file rather than doing it yourself:
    return new FilePathResult( imagefileName, "image/jpeg" ); // assuming all images are JPEGs.
}
```

In your page, use an `<img />` element like so:

```
<img src="@( this.Url.Action("GetImage", new { imageName = "foo" } ) )" />
```

In ASP.NET WebForms you'll need to use an `*.ashx` instead, but the principle is the same.